# Inno Setup: set visibility of TCheckbox

Tags: installation, visibility, inno-setup

i have a question regarding inno setup.
I want to change the Visibility of a TCheckbox in my 
`procedure CurPageChanged(const CurPageID: integer);` to false, so that when the page displays i don't see the checkbox anymore.
 My code looks as follows

```
if CurPageID=wpSelectComponents then begin
    GetDirectoryFromComponentsTxt();
    if Update_FP = true then
    begin 
      if CheckUpdateVersion() then 
      begin
//Here should be the change to invisible
      end
      else begin
        if Flag_IsSilentInstallation = false then begin
           if MsgBox(GetLanguageString('VersionIncompatible', 40053), mbError, MB_YESNO)= IDYES then
           begin 
             //aaaaand here should be also a change to invisible
           end

           else begin 
              Quit();
           end
        end
        ...
```

As far as i can see i can't toggle it to invisible here.
Does anybody has a different perspective on how i can change the visibility during runtime.

And as always Thanks in advance.

Comment: `NameOfYourCheckbox.Visible := true` and `NameOfYourCheckbox.Visible := false`?

Comment: This results in a Runtime Error (at 267:191)       Could not call proc

Comment: Your `NameOfYourCheckbox: TNewCheckBox;` should be a `Global Var`.

Comment: It's Global but its a TCheckBox and not a TNewCheckBox. Is there any difference ?

Comment: Is the checkbox created in `procedure InitializeWizard();`? Because if the checkbox is not created before you want to hide it or show it, then you will get the error.

Comment: Okay i havn't initialized it in the InitializeWizard because in other procedures i can use the variable. Is it possible that it is initialized by standard anywhere else?

Comment: It has to be created before Components Page and you have to set Components Page as the Owner of the Checkbox. The easiest way is to create the element in `InitialiazeWizard` procedure and then manage it on the `CurPageChanged`. But problably @TLama will give you more specific and better solution/comment.